# Can we run karate tests on GraalVM JDK?

Tags: spring-boot, karate, spring-boot-test

I have a REST API running on Springboot 3 and I test it using the karate framework.

As native is a new feature of springboot 3 I tried to run the API on GraalVM.
My app can run but when it comes to running tests I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find option with name js.ecmascript-version.
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalArgument(PolyglotEngineException.java:131)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.OptionValuesImpl.failNotFound(OptionValuesImpl.java:274)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.parseOptions(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:736)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.<init>(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:313)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotImpl.buildEngine(PolyglotImpl.java:288)
at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:625)
```

I use GraalVM 22.3.0 and karate-junit5 1.1.0 (I also tried more recent versions but it does not work).
Is there a compatibility problem between the Karate framework and the graalVM since the karate core already uses graaljs dependencies ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, can you first try 1.4.0.RC3 and refer this thread - or comment there also with your findings: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2148

But if you want to use the GraalVM instead of a normal JVM, I don't think that's supported. But a PR is welcome.